# sox FAIL trim error

Tags: python, sox

I am using sox library http://sox.sourceforge.net .
My app & music files（test1.wav&test2.wav） are in Desktop/test directory.
So I wrote command in terminal of Desktop/test directory

```
sox -m suzu0.wav -v 0.2 suzu1.wav 0_1.wav trim 0 10 suzu03_len
```

I got an error,

```
sox FAIL trim: Error parsing position 3
sox FAIL trim: usage: {position}
```

I think the way to designate time trim is wrong,  so I rewrite command like

```
sox -m suzu0.wav -v 0.2 suzu1.wav 0_1.wav trim 0 suzu03_len
```

I got an error

```
sox FAIL trim: Error parsing position 2
sox FAIL trim: usage: {position}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like suzu03_len may be coming in as a string when it needs to be an interval